# login to local and server

Tags: php, codeigniter

how to log on localhost mark must be changed at the server login below to log in the server , and ENVIRONMENT == "development " is not called server and ENVIRONMENT == " test " called Server , without change of ENVIRONMENT == " test "?

```html
if($email == NULL || $pass == NULL) return array("success"=>0,"msg"=>"Email dan password harus diisi");
        else
        {
            if (ENVIRONMENT == "development") 
                {
                $data['result'] =Array
                 (
                'message' => 'Success',
                'code' => 00,
                'obj' => Array  ('loginTried' => 0,
                                'email' => 'maheswara@gmail.com',
                                'phoneNumber' => 089615378878,
                                'name' => 'Dika',
                                'point' => 10, ));

                    return array("success"=>1,"msg"=>"Logged in");   
                
                }
                else 
                {
                    $pass  = md5($pass);
                    $url = "http://tooz.co.";

                    $post =  json_encode(array('email' => $email, 'userPassword' => $pass));
                    $fields_string = "";
                    $fields = array(
                        'logintikiid' =>  $post
                    );

                    //url-ify the data for the POST
                    foreach($fields as $key=>$value)
                    { 
                        $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; 
                    }
                    rtrim($fields_string, '&');

                    //open connection
                    $ch = curl_init();

                    //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
                    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
                    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
                    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
                    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);

                    //execute post
                    $result = curl_exec($ch);

                    //close connection
                    curl_close($ch);

                    $data = json_decode($result,TRUE);

                    if($data['code']=="00")
                    {
                        
                        $this->CI->session->user_email = $data['obj']['email'];
                        $this->CI->session->user_phone = $data['obj']['phoneNumber'];
                        $this->CI->session->user_name  = $data['obj']['name'];
                        $this->CI->session->tooz_point = $data['obj']['point'];
                        
                        return array("success"=>1,"msg"=>"Logged in");   
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return array("success"=>0,"msg"=>"Email dan password salah");
                    }
                }
        }      
        
    }
```

this is controler

```html
public function index($from=NULL)
 {
  $data = array();

  switch ($from) {
   case 'pickup':
   $redirect = base_url("pickup");
   set_top_msg("Untuk mengakses fitur pickup, silahkan login terlebih dahulu");
   break;
   case 'book':
   $redirect = base_url("book");
   set_top_msg("Untuk mengakses fitur booking, silahkan login terlebih dahulu");
   break;
   default:
   $redirect = base_url();
   break;
  }
  if ($this->session->user_email)
  {
   header("location:". base_url("tooz"));
   die();
  }
  
  else if($this->input->post())
  {
   $this->load->library("login_library");
   $email = $this->input->post("email");
   $pass  = $this->input->post("pass");

   $return = $this->login_library->login($email,$pass);

   if($return['success']==1)header('Location:'. $redirect);
   else set_top_msg($return["msg"],"warning");
  }
  load_page($data);
 }
```